# Insert result of a Query using aggregation subquery as filter into new collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I implement this query in MongoDB

```
select * into NewTable 
from SalesInvoice where SalesID in 
   (select SalesID from SalesInvoice 
        group by CustomerID 
          having count(CustomerID)>1
    )
```

I could build the aggregate query, but couldn't find a way to make a new query and use the aggregate query as a filter and then insert the result into new collection.

Below is aggregate query:

```
db.SalesInvoice.aggregate([ {$group: {_id:"$request.CustomerID", count: {$sum:1}}},{$match: {count: {$gt:1}}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Think there are a few approaches to achieve:

**Approach 1**

1. `$lookup` - Left join with the self-collection by `CustomerID` and return a salesInvoices` array.
2. `$match` - Filter the document with the size of the `salesInvoices` array with more than 1.
3. `$unset` - Remove the `salesInvoices` array.
4. [`out`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) - Export the result into the collection.

```
db.SalesInvoice.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "SalesInvoice",
      let: {
        custID: "$CustomerID"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$CustomerID",
                "$$custID"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "salesInvoices"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$salesInvoices"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "salesInvoices"
  },
  {
    $out: "<Your new collection>"
  }
])
```

[Demo Approach 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AJtpGuYeQyG)

---

**Approach 2**

1. `$facet` - Allow multiple aggregation pipelines to be run in a single query.

   1.1. `salesInvoices` - Return all documents from the *salesInvoices* collection.

   1.2. `filterCustomers` - Get the `CustomerID` that appeared in more than 1 document in the *salesInvoices* collection.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `salesInvoices` array.
3. `$match` - Filter the document by matching `SalesInvoices.CustomerID`.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `SalesInvoices` field.
5. [`out`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) - Export the result into the collection.

```
db.SalesInvoice.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      salesInvoices: [],
      filteredCustomers: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$CustomerID",
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            count: {
              $gt: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$salesInvoices"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$salesInvoices.CustomerID",
          "$filteredCustomers._id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$salesInvoices"
  },
  {
    $out: "<Your new collection>"
  }
])
```

[Demo Approach 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eS57Ob-d6JR)